# copyteximage2D in terms of state machine

Tags: webgl

i dont know how copyteximage2D works, 
i would like a explanation in term of the webgl state machine :

thanks to gman i have this :

```
gl = { 
    activeTextureUnit: 0,
    textureUnits: [],
};

gl.activeTexture = function(unit) {
    this.activeTextureUnit = unit - this.TEXTURE_0;  
};

gl.bindTexture = function(bindPoint, texture) {
    var textureUnit = this.textureUnits[this.activeTextureUnit];
    switch (bindPoint) {
       case this.TEXTURE_2D:
         textureUnit.texture2D = texture;
         break;
       case ....
    }
};
gl.copyTexImage2D = function( target, level, iformat, x, y, w,h,b) {
.....
..... gman please your code here thanks very much!!!
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyTexImage2D` copies from the current framebuffer or canvas into the given target of the current texture unit

```
gl = {
  activeTextureUnit: 0,
  textureUnits: [
    { gl.TEXTURE_2D: null, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { gl.TEXTURE_2D: null, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { gl.TEXTURE_2D: null, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    { gl.TEXTURE_2D: null, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP: null, ... },
    ...
  ],
  framebufferBindPoints: {
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER: gl.canvas.internalFramebuffer,
  },
};

gl.bindFramebuffer = function(bindPoint, framebuffer) {
  this.framebufferBindPoints[bindPoint] = 
     framebuffer ? framebuffer : gl.canvas.internalFramebuffer;
}; 

gl.copyTexImage2D = function( target, level, iformat, x, y, w,h,b) {
  var textureUnit = this.textureUnits[this.activeTextureUnit];
  var texture = textureUnit[target];
  var framebuffer = this.framebufferBindPoints[gl.FRAMEBUFFER];
  // copy from framebuffer into texture
}
```

Comment: nice!! So, if , before the gl.copyTex.. i put   `fbPV2 = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbPV2);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, pvTex2, 0); ` so pvTex2 will be copy to the texture bound to the current textureUnit ?

Comment: Yes `pxTex2` will be the source for whatever texture you decide to copyTexImage2D to.

Comment: ok ! now i'm facing with another problem : pvTex2 is a float texture. It seems  it may be the problem ? or may be the problem is that i did not make a generatemimap (or set the filter) after the copyTexImage2D ?

Comment: ok, generatemimap is trivial. And i guess from what i find that copyteximage2D not work with float textures. So i am going to use a shader and draw the texture in a framebuffer in order to achieve the copy !

Comment: Where you copying from float to float? I don't remember the limitations off the top of my head. Yea, copying with a shader though is a common solution. Chrome even does this behind the scenes for certain situations.